# "goal to do" or "goal of doing"?

Tags: usage, synonyms

In this sentence:

> Looking towards our goal ***of reaching*** a better performance, we will use more efficient strategies.

Would ***to reach*** be more correct in this context, or are the expressions ***goal of doing*** and ***goal to do*** always interchangeable? Is there any distinction between the two uses?

I found instances of both on the internet:

> In 1961, President Kennedy set a goal to reach the moon "before this decade is out". ([Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/a+goal+to+reach))

and

> Health Secretary Matt Hancock announced he was “setting the goal” of reaching 100,000 tests for coronavirus per day by the end of April.
> ([Somerset Live](https://www.somersetlive.co.uk/news/uk-world-news/government-setting-goal-reaching-100000-4013923))

Comment: See how the two constructions have competed over time: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=goal+of+doing%2Cgoal+to+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoal%20of%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoal%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @RonaldSole: So I should go with "goal of reaching" because it is more frequently used? Is that the only difference?

Comment: Either way is fine.

Comment: @RonaldSole On the other hand, if you just look for "goal of/goal to", the results look very different: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=goal+of%2Cgoal+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoal%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoal%20to%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score -1):

Considering the example above:

> Looking towards our goal of reaching a better performance, we will use
> more efficient strategies.

This seems to be an example of the [passive voice](https://www.hamilton.edu/academics/centers/writing/seven-sins-of-writing/1#:%7E:text=Passive%20voice%20produces%20a%20sentence,creates%20clearer%2C%20more%20concise%20sentences.). It makes sense and you can totally say it without sounding weird, but it does feel a little high-brow. One could change it to be "...towards our goal to reach better performance..." and subjectively convey the speaker's greater stake in achieving the goal.

Comment: I didn't quite catch the difference between the two. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct and used interchangeably.